# ZK FOUR LETTER : An error occurred while using the zk.FLWSrvr function in the go-zookeeper/zk library in Golang

Tags: go, apache-zookeeper

The second return value of zk.FLWSrvr is false, indicating an error during the parsing process. The returned ServerStats contains a piece of information stating that the regular expression could not be parsed. Why is this? Is the usage of the zk.FLWSrvr function related to the version of Zookeeper?

```
    serverStats,success=zk.FLWSrvr(zkConfig.Hosts,time.Duration(model.Zk4LetterTimeout)*time.Second)
    if !success {
        log.Println("response data = ", serverStats[0])
        return probeValueMap, errors.New("phase zookeeper response data unsuccessful")
    }
    if serverStats == nil || len(serverStats) == 0 {
        return probeValueMap, errors.New("echo Srvr failed before get serverStats")
    }
```

log information:

> response data =  &{100.105.46.232:2118 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC unknown  unable to parse fields from zookeeper response (no regex matches)}

Could it be that the functions in the go-zookeeper/zk library are not versatile enough? Or did I make a mistake somewhere?